# UILocalNotification launched every minute util user click it

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification, alarm

If I set my notification like the code below, it would launch alarm every minute. However, it gets triggered even my alarm is set behind the current time. For example, the current time is 12:00 and the alarm time is 9:00, it still gets triggered because kCFCalendarUnitMinute is a loop.

How can I get the function as my title description?

```
    UILocalNotification *localNotification = [UILocalNotification new];
    localNotification.userInfo = @{@"status":@"alarm",@"note":noteString,@"index":@(index)};
    localNotification.fireDate = dateToFire;
    localNotification.alertTitle = @"Alarm";
    localNotification.alertBody = @"Wake Up!";
    localNotification.soundName = @"myTone.m4a";
    localNotification.alertAction = @"View";
    localNotification.repeatInterval = kCFCalendarUnitMinute;
    localNotification.regionTriggersOnce = true;
    localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber =
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber + 1;
    localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];

    // To set the local notification
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

Comment: How are you setting `dateToFire`?

Comment: the dateToFire is from what user select from a UIPickerView

Comment: So, it seems that you are allowing them to pick a date/time in the pat. If it is now 10 and they pick 9 you seem to be setting the date to 9 *today* so the notification fires immediately

Comment: the reason is localNotification.repeatInterval is set to kCFCalendarUnitMinute. if I set it to kCFCalendarUnitWeekMonth, it will not be triggered every minute even user set 9 but current hour is 10.

Comment: Yes, but `dateToFire` consists of a date and a time.  If it is now 10 am and you want the notification to fire at 9 am *tomorrow* you need to make sure you are setting the date portion appropriately.  If it is 8 am and you want the notification at 9, then you need to set the date to *today*; check what you are setting `dateToFire` to

Comment: yes, the date and time are both correctly be set.